# Trouble Writing to file

Tags: arrays, file, netlogo

i'm having trouble finishing off this model.  The concept is for questions to be asked to a range of turtles.  Each turtle represents a single domain of knowledge and each question should contain multiple random domains of knowledge.  Turtles whose ID matches one of the domains in the question are asked to answer.  Their answer is then rated based on the turtle's abilities and expertise.

I am hoping that I have the bones of the code together but I'm unable to verify this until I can get some output to Excel.  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong with my 'write' instructions?  When I run the model, no file is updated or created.  And can you spot any other defects in the code?

Thanks,
John

```
globals
[question
answer]

turtles-own 
[abilities 
expertise 
expert
]

to setup
clear-all
file-open "/Users/johnhayes/ProjectFile.csv"
create-turtles 500
set question []
set answer []
reset-ticks
end

to go
ask turtles [initialise-turtles]
create-question
set answer []
ask turtles [give-an-answer]
evaluate
show (list "relevance quality" answer)
stop
tick
if ticks >= 1000 [file-close stop]
print-answers
end

to initialise-turtles ; turtle proc 1
set abilities (random 10)   ; abilities assigned randomly to each turtle. 
set expertise (random 10)   ; expertise assigned randomly to each turtle.
set expert (FALSE)         
end

to create-question
set question n-of 500 turtles 
end

to give-an-answer ; turtle proc 2
if member? self question
[ set expert TRUE ]  ; mark as expert    
end

to evaluate ; turtle proc 3
let expert-group no-turtles
set expert-group (turtles with [expert = TRUE])  
show (list ([abilities] of expert-group))        
show (list ([expertise] of expert-group))       
set answer lput (sum [abilities] of expert-group) answer set answer lput (sum[expertise] of expert-group) answer
end

to print-answers
file-open "/Users/johnhayes/ProjectFile.csv"
file-print answer    
file-close    
end
```

Answer (score -1):

'\' is the escape character in netlogo to have it read as \ you have to double it up.

```
file-open "/Users/johnhayes/ProjectFile.csv"
```

Becomes

```
file-open "\\Users\\johnhayes\\ProjectFile.csv"
```

Then Project will open or be created.

You may want to look into using BehaviorSpace  for output it is found under tools and allows you to have all the output from various runs of your model in one .csv Click on new and follow the instructions.

In your case use answer as your reporter.

Edit slash dyslexia.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated but I'm still not getting a printed file. I've just realised the ticks count isn't updating when I run the model but I am getting output in the command centre.

Comment: I figured it out. Your solution solved my printing file issue but there was a command to 'Stop' the procedure before it wrote to the file. Silly mistake on my part!

Comment: Have fun netlogo is the bee's knees

Comment: NetLogo's escape character is the backslash, not the forward slash.